# JSX Element Type Error: Adding Types to object returned from .map function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, types, typescript-typings

I'm trying to add the `item` **type to the object that is returned from the .map function**. However, I'm getting a JSX error and I tried adding `item: JSX.Element` to the Item type, but that doesn't seem to work correctly. Can someone clarify this for me? Below is the error, types, and code.

**Error:**

```
src/ListPicker.tsx:69:28 - error TS2345: Argument of type '(item: Item) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => Element'.
  Types of parameters 'item' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Item'.

      {props.items.map((item: Item) => {
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

**Types:**

```
// TypeScript: Types
interface Props {
  title: string,
  items: Array<string>,
  onPress: Function,
  onValueChange: Function,
}

interface Item {
  label: string,
  value: string,
  key: number | string,
  color: string,
};
```

**ListPicker.tsx:**

```
// Render iOS Picker
  const renderIOSPicker = () => {
    try {
      return (
        <Picker
          selectedValue={value}
          onValueChange={selectValue}>
          {props.items.map((item: Item) => {
            return (
              <Picker.Item
                label={item.label}
                value={item.value}
                key={item.key || item.label}
                color={item.color}
              />
            );
          })}
        </Picker>
      )
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Looks like your props define `items` to be an array of strings, so when mapping over an array of strings the map callback signature is `(element: string, index: number, array: string[])`. I think if you update props interface for `items` to be `items: Array<Item>,`, it should now match up. If this is correct then I can add as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your props define `items` to be an array of strings, so when mapping over an array of strings the map callback signature is `(element: string, index: number, array: string[])`. I think if you update props interface for `items` to be `items: Array<Item>,`, it should now match up.

```
// TypeScript: Types
interface Item {
  label: string,
  value: string,
  key: number | string,
  color: string,
};

interface Props {
  title: string,
  items: Array<Item>, // use array of type you defined above
  onPress: Function,
  onValueChange: Function,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the issue here is inconsistentcy between the type of `item` (ie in the argument of your map function), and the type the `items` array as defined in the `Props` interface.

Your `Props` interface defines the `items` field as an array of strings, where as your rendering code expects the `items` field to be an array of `Item` objects.

If you are able to revise and refactor your code so the `Props` is defined as:

```
interface Props {
  title: string,
  items: Array<Item>,
  onPress: Function,
  onValueChange: Function,
}
```

Then this should resolve the error.